# LocalBroadcastManager not receiving broadcasts in a Activity

Tags: android, android-activity, service, android-context, localbroadcastmanager

I am using a LocalBroadcastManager to make broadcast to my activtiy and services using APPLICATION CONTEXT , like this:

```
public class CommonForApp extends Application{
    public void broadcastUpdateUICommand(String[] updateFlags,
                String[] flagValues) {
            Intent intent = new Intent(UPDATE_UI_BROADCAST);
            for (int i = 0; i < updateFlags.length; i++) {
                intent.putExtra(updateFlags[i], flagValues[i]);
            }

            mLocalBroadcastManager = LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(mContext);
            mLocalBroadcastManager.sendBroadcast(intent);

        }}
```

Now Using a Listener in my Service, I am calling broadcastUpdateUICommand() ,like this:

```
public class mService extends Service {
    public BuildNowPLaylistListListener buildCursorListener = new BuildNowPLaylistListListener() {

            @Override
            public void onServiceListReady() {
    mApp.broadcastUpdateUICommand(
                        new String[] { CommonForApp.INIT_DRAWER},
                        new String[] {""});

            }}}
```

And i am receiving the broadcast in my Activity, like this:

```
public class mActivity extends Activity{
    BroadcastReceiver mReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {

            @Override
            public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
           mtoast.showtext("in onreceive"); //toast to check 

                if (intent.hasExtra(CommonForApp.INIT_DRAWER))
                    initialiseDrawer();

    }};


}
```

mApp is instance of Application.
CommonForApp is my Application Class.

But in my activity i am not receving any broadcast(the broadcast manager is initialised using application context) .

Can Anyone suggest me why i am not receiving broadcast in my activity? ..

.Thanks in advance !

Comment: Reason For downvote ...Plz

Comment: Is the `Activity` running when you send the broadcast? Are you sure you're registering the Receiver with the correct `IntentFilter` in the `Activity`? Also, why don't you just broadcast directly from the `Service`?

Comment: where is registration for messages in activity?

Comment: @MikeM. Yes Activity is running ;,    i cannt directly broadcast From Service According to my code implementation.

Comment: @StepanMaksymov Sendbroadcast() is from application context so i dont need to register it.

Comment: Uh, no. You still need to register the Receiver.

Comment: @MikeM. How i will register ? Can you Please suggest me .i am new in using broadcast receivers.

Comment: what are you talking about? `LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(this).registerReceiver(... // in activity in onCreate` and `LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(this).unregisterReceiver(...// in onDestroy`

Comment: @StepanMaksymov I tried that too ...but it is still not working.....do i need to register in manifest also ?

Comment: check this https://developer.android.com/training/run-background-service/report-status.html

Comment: check my answer to be clear.

Comment: @skadoosh yeah i was doing mistake in intentfilter ....thanks a lot for pointing it out:)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

in activity:

```
protected BroadcastReceiver mMessageReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, final Intent intent) {
        runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                if(intent.hasExtra("type")){
                    // Do some action
                }
            }
        });

    }
};

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState, PersistableBundle persistentState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState, persistentState);
    LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(this).registerReceiver(mMessageReceiver,
            new IntentFilter("data-loaded"));
}

protected void onDestroy() {
    super.onDestroy();
    LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(this).unregisterReceiver(mMessageReceiver);
}
```

then you send broadcast:

```
public static void sendBroadcastMessageDataLoaded(Context context, String dataType){
    Intent intent = new Intent("data-loaded");
    intent.putExtra("type", dataType);
    LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(context).sendBroadcast(intent);
}
```

Comment: BRoadcastreceiver not working aftersometime ...why so ?

Comment: activity can be killed when low memory )

Comment: @developer I had a broadcast receiver in my service and noticed that on some phones, Android kills the service after some time - then the broadcast receiver stopped working :/

Comment: depends how you start service, and you can check if service run before sending broadcast if not run then you can start it )

Comment: you saved my day